# InDesign: how to build "numbered" lists that re-start numbering correctly

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, lists

I'm typesetting a booklet that uses a Paragraph Style for a "numbered" list (I'm using A,B,C,D ...). Its probably a simple fix but I can't figure out how once I'm done with one list and move on to the next one later on, to have the numbering automatically restart there, i.e. with A instead of the list continuing the numbering from the previous list. The Mode option under Numbering Style doesn't include this kind of option – I tried the Start At option but this is what I get:

[image]

I don't see anywhere else to make this happen automatically. Right now I'm just using "Convert Bullets and Numbering to Text" option under Type → Bulleted and Numbered Lists in order to restart the lists. Again I'm sure this has been done a million times I just don't know how it's done.

Comment: I tried very hard to understand your request, but I still don't get it. When exactly do you want that your paragraph restarts at "A"? After a certain paragraph style (title, list or whatever)? In that case, you just need to create a multilevel list. Please be more specific, using screenshot of what you want to achieve at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

Place the cursor on the first paragraph of your second list, go to 'Bullets & Numbering' and change the mode from 'Continue from previous number' to 'Start At' and type '1' in the next box.

[image]

Comment: I did try that – in the edited post I put a screenshot of what I get when I try that, i.e. the same list item repeating.

Comment: That apparently happens if you select all the paragraphs. Try just placing the cursor inside the first paragraph with no selection.